# Dealing with wrapped types (two nested functions) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Imagine, we have two (could be more) functions `logicA` and `logicB` with different params but same return type `CommonRes`.

**We want to**:

- Access them via some key-value (e.g. as a module export)
- Each time apply the same `postprocessing` wrapper for the functions result

**Real world example:** the functions are preparing API requests by some templates (with different params), we want to group them (together with API calling logic as "postprocessing") in some reusable module

**The possible solution**:

```
 logicA = (params: ParamsA): CommonRes
 logicB = (params: ParamsB): CommonRes

 type PostprocessorFn = (res: CommonRes) => Promise<string>
    
 postprocessing = async (res: CommonRes) => {
             
 const someResultString = await something(...)
    return someResultString
 })
    
 const wrappedLogic = new Proxy({
    a: (wrapper: PostprocessorFn) => (params: ParamsA) => wrapper(logicA(params)), 
    b: (wrapper: PostprocessorFn) => (params: ParamsB) => wrapper(logicB(params)), 
 }, {
    get(target, key) {
       return target[key](postprocessing)
    }
 })
```

**The problem**:
When we'll try to use it as:

```
wrappedLogic.a({somethingFromParamsA: 'some'})
```

We'll get type script error:

```
Argument of type {somethingFromParamsA: string} is not assignable to parameter of type 'PostprocessorFn'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'somethingFromParamsA' does not exist in type 'PostprocessorFn'
```

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] others can paste into their own IDEs to demonstrate your problem for themselves. Among other things that means: any third-party or private types or values you reference should be defined or declared (or even better, replaced with built-in things); and, syntactically invalid pseudocode should be replaced with valid versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried fiddleing a little with the example you provided and was able to change the proxy code in order to remove the error and maintain the correct typesafety in the function arguments:

```js
const wrappedLogic = new Proxy({
   a: (param: ParamsA) => logicA(param), 
   b: (param: ParamsB) => logicB(param), 
}, {
   get(target, key) {
      return (...args) => postprocessing(target[key](...args))
   }
})

wrappedLogic.a({somethingFromParamsA: "test logic A"})
wrappedLogic.b({somethingFromParamsB: "test logic B"})
```

This code should have the same effect of the one you presented.
Indeed, it does have a warning about the `args` parameter with the spread operator, but I saw that the function arguments when called are still correctly typed, so it doesn't seem to be an issue. This is because typescript is relying only on the object definition in order to get the argument types.

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. It looks great and seems to cover all the necessary cases! I was just wondering if the autocomplete feature will still work correctly for both the A and B cases? Thank you for your help!

Comment: As long as you don't explicitly set the `target` parameter to `any`, it should autocomplete the `a` and `b` on the proxy. Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: This complete solution doesn't have any errors, but I'm not sure it's really a sustainable way to write that code, I would just endure those 2 warnings. Here it is a link to the playground: https://playcode.io/1467787

Comment: The great solution, but still breaks typings in case we'll modify `PostprocessorFn` return type (in reality I have them different as it's an API response)  to 
`type PostprocessorFn = (res: CommonRes) => Promise<{otherField: number}>`
And e.g. 
`const postprocessing:  PostprocessorFn = async (res: CommonRes) => {
   ...
    return {
        otherField: 123,
    }
}`

Then resA.otherField will give us `Property 'otherField' does not exist on type 'CommonRes'.`

Comment: Hi Sergey, try looking at it again, I've made a change: https://playcode.io/1467787